# Distributing Win32 Application Practice: Windows Smart-screen compliant

Tags: windows, winapi, certificate, sign

My WinAPI C++ program is causing Windows Smart-Screen to popup (when I download it then try to run it). Rightly so because I haven't digitally signed it or etc.

What things should be done to a WinAPI application (&/or) installer to make it Windows Smart-Screen compliant? Is it just signing the exe & installer with `SignTool` or are there other things? Do I have to purchase/register a certificate? Can I generate my own for free? Any other steps to do to produce a 'well behaved'/Smart-Screen compliant Win32 application?

Comment: I thought SmartScreen only affected files downloaded from the Internet. Has this been extended in later version of Windows?

Comment: @CodyGray you'd probably know more about it than me. But yes, for me the problem was only occurring when I downloaded my installer and/or exe. Which is what my users will do also (thats how they will get the installer)

Comment: Smart Screen won't pass a self signed cert, so you will need to get one signed by an external service that is, itself, authorized to sign certificates by one of the root CA certs that are installed by default.

Comment: What happens if you zip your installer? Anyway, code signing certs aren't really that expensive.

Comment: Buy a cert. It wouldn't be much use of anyone could just sign there own files. Where's the trust in that.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/05/17/smartscreen-application-reputation-in-ie9/
Here is a blog post that is interesting. It implies that you can build reputation, for even a self signed cert, as long as some users download your app, accept the smart screen warning and the app is not later flagged as malware your smart screen warning incidence should eventually drop.
Use the same cert on subsequent products should transfer the built up trust.